# Are "disabled" _POST variable form elements empty Server-Side?

Tags: html, forms, input, disabled-input

I have the following `<input>` form element:

```
<input id="serviceCode" name="serviceCode" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" maxlength="4" value="T2" disabled="">
```

It's strange but this does not come back to the server as a `$_POST['serviceCode']` variable. Am I missing something or are "disabled" input form elements not passed back to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled elements are not posted to the server [as per the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled) :

> ... it cannot
>   receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form.

If you wanted to access these values, you might consider making the element `readonly` or storing the value in a hidden element and using another disabled element to display it.

Comment: Well, that explains it then. Thank you @RionWilliams.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's right.

Disabled form elements are not send when the form is submitted.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-disabled:

> The disabled attribute is used to make the control non-interactive and to prevent its value from being submitted.”
>   If you don’t want the user to be able to change the values, but still send them with the form when it is submitted – use the readonly attribute instead.